# How to copy two different cell values in cells of one column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a column Z which contains values like

```
A
B
B
B
B
A
B
B
B
```

There can be any number of B's after one A in column Z.
Cell X1 contains the value "firsttext" and cell Y1 contains the value "secondtext"
I want some Excel formula to make my column W look like below:

```
firsttext
secondtext
{Blank}
{Blank}
{Blank}
firsttext
secondtext
{Blank}
{Blank}
```

So corresponding to each A value in column Z I want the value "firsttext" in Column W and in the following cell I want the value "secondtext" and after that each cell should remain blank until next A value appears in column Z.

I used formulas like `W=IF(Z1="A",$X$1,$Y$1)`. But this formula is copying "secondtext" corresponding to each B value which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Add a nested if:

```
=IF(Z1="A",$X$1,IF(INDEX(Z:Z,MAX(ROW()-1,1))="A",$Y$1,""))
```

the `INDEX(Z:Z,MAX(ROW()-1,1))` looks into the Z column one row above the current on.  as you are putting this in Row 1 we need to deal with the fact that there is no row 0.

You could also put your formula in W1 then put this in W2:

```
=IF(Z2="A",$X$1,IF(Z1="A",$Y$1,""))
```

and copy down.

Comment: Meanwhile my formula also worked with W1=IF(Z1<>"",$X$1,"") and W2=IF(AND(Z2<>"B",Z2<>""),$X$1,IF(V1=$X$1,$Y$1,"")) and copy down.But you solved it in one formula itself so kudos to you.

Comment: Scott, Also is there any formula to get values in V column cells as firsttext and secondtext as many times as A appear in Z.Means if A appears 4 times in Z column then V column populates with V1= firsttext and V2=secondtext and so on that till V8?